# delegate doesn't fire in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, delegates, webforms, paging

I am trying to write custom paging in one of data server control in c#. My delegate doesn't fire. Following is the code.

I have following markup:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

following C# code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            PageSize = 3;
            using (var db = new MyDBEntities())
            {
                Repeater1.DataSource = db.Enquiries.ToList().Take(3);
                Repeater1.DataBind();
                PrintNumber();
            }
        }
    }

    private void PrintNumber()
    {
        using (var db = new MyDBEntities())
        {
            var total = db.Enquiries.Count();
            var division = total / PageSize;
            var mod = total % PageSize;
            totalPages = mod == 0 ? division : division + 1;


            for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++)
            {
                LinkButton btn = new LinkButton();
                btn.Text = i.ToString();
                btn.ID = "PagerButton" + i.ToString();
                btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(btn);

            }
        }
    }

    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = (Button)sender;
        var txt = btn.Text;
    }
```

i have following rendered markup.

```
<a id="PagerButton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PagerButton1','')">1</a>
<a id="PagerButton2" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PagerButton2','')">2</a>
<a id="PagerButton3" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PagerButton3','')">3</a>
```

My delegate doesn't fire when link button clicked. Please help.. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks StackOverflow users. I have solved this problem. I was adding linkbutton controls in Page_Load event. My Dynamically added buttons were not binding because of its loaded state. I added my dynamic button in Page_Init event and its working. Cheers.